# Selenium : NoSuchElementException in IE11 JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to execute selenium webdriver java code in IE11 , it throws "NoSuchElementException"  even after the page is loaded completely.

1. Web driver : IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.0
2. IE version : 11
3. selenium : selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar
4. java : jdk1.8

The application consists of LoginPage and home page. In Home Page, customers details can be added after clicking "Add customer" button.

Logging into the application is executing successfully in IE11. After log in, NoSuchElementException is thrown for "Add customer" button.

The following is the selenium Java code:

```
     driver.findElement(By.id("btnAddCustToQueue")).click();
```

The following is the jsp code :

```
    <DIV class="blueButton floatLeft pie_first-child" id=btnAddCustToQueue onclick=openAddCustomer() _pieId="_158">Add<BR>Customer </DIV>
```

Below is the exception thrown :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == btnAddCustToQueue (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

I have used explicit wait for the "Add customer" button to load. In this case, "TimeOutException" as show below:

```
     Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: btnAddCustToQueue
```

The same code works fine with CHROME browser.
I am not sure whether there is problem with latest IE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Have you got any solution?

Comment: can you replicate this on public URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//DIV[contains(@id,'btnAddCustToQueue')")).click();
```

It should work if the HTML you uploaded is this

Next time upload the webpage you are trying this on so we can try this out to and maybe find a better method like that.